# Can a List of Resources be used in the depends_on Property

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Can a resource's `depends_on` be used against all elements in a "resource list". For example, in the resource below, the source_ids' property is enumerated, however, I get an error when I attempt to concat() those elements in the `depends_on` with other elements.

The code below is valid and deploys, however, I don’t know if that is a valid construct for `depends_on`. Does it wait for all elements in the “resource collection”? If not, is there a better alternative?

In the example below, `resource aws_dms_replication_instance.dms_instances{}` contains more than one instance.

```
resource "aws_dms_event_subscription" "event_subscription_repl_instance_bronze" {

    count               = length(lookup(var.dms_notification_emails, terraform.workspace))    
     ...   
    source_ids           = [for ri in aws_dms_replication_instance.dms_instances : ri.replication_instance_id]
   
    depends_on = [
         aws_dms_replication_instance.dms_instances         
        ]    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you do not need `depends_on` as you have existing implicit relation already setup through:

```
source_ids           = [for ri in aws_dms_replication_instance.dms_instances : ri.replication_instance_id]
```

So `depends_on` is redundant. But yes, it will wait for all instances of `aws_dms_replication_instance.dms_instances` to be deployed if you did not have `source_ids`.

Comment: Thank you for the correction and explanation.